# ansible community.aws.ec2_elb not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-elb

EDIT: I guess I was using the wrong module, see my own answer.

I am trying to run this ansible module:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/ec2_elb_module.html

I am running it like this, basically following the example:

```
---
- hosts: all 
  #gather_facts: no 

  pre_tasks:

  - name: Instance De-register
    community.aws.ec2_elb:
      aws_access_key: <key>
      aws_secret_key: <secret>
      instance_id: "{{ id }}"
      state: absent
      region: us-east-1
    register: dereg

  - name: print output
    debug: 
      var: dereg
```

The response I get:

```
ok: [<ip>] => {
    "dereg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "ec2_elbs": []
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

The instance id is in the inventory file and is the AWS instance id.
The inventory file looks like this:

```
[hosts]
<ip> id=i-<AWS-ID>
<ip> id=i-<AWS-ID>
```

And I am calling the script: `ansible-playbook -i inventory deregister.yml`

The nodes exist, are running and are attached to a target group of the load balancer, the listener is configured and the target group sees the nodes as healthy.

There's not much documentation and I have no idea why it doesn't work.

What I want to achieve is that when I update my node, it first deregisters it from the AWS load balancer, as it takes x amount of seconds until the load balancer will see the target as unhealthy and will route requests for this time to it, which will fail.

Comment: Well it does what you want does it? `"ec2_elbs": []` ends up empty because you stated that you want the existing load balancer to be `state: absent`. Your task didn't fail: `"failed": false`, it didn't do anything, though: `"changed": false`, probably because you removed the load balancer already on previous trials.

Comment: huh? The load balancer is still there and the target group still has all the nodes connected. No instances got de-registered...Am I expecting something wrong here?

Comment: From the synopsis: *This module de-registers or registers an AWS EC2 instance from the ELBs that it belongs to.* Are you trying to de-register EC2 or something else? The answer from the tasks seems to say that there is no ELB connected to this EC2, hence the empty list returned by the fact.

Comment: I am trying to deregister 2 ec2 instances which are registered as targets to a target group of a load balancer. on AWS

Comment: Mhm, I'd expect the target group to be your issue. This task is to disconnect ELB from EC2 that are directly connected. You should give a try at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/elb_target_group_module.html. Looks like you can act on the targets there: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/elb_target_group_module.html#parameter-targets

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, I will check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this to work now - by using a different module.

I guess this module only works with the Classic LB (or something like that).

By using the `community.aws.elb_target` module I got it to work with the AWS ALB we were using.
Sorry for creating confusion. Should probably adjust title